# remove groups of spaces

Tags: sed, awk, solaris

I have a text file where I want to remove groups of 2 or more space characters for each line.

Here is an example of a line:

```
Company Management                                      Company Management                                      Company Management Reports                              Shipment - Text                                                                     Program
```

Here is what it should be:

```
Company Management  Company Management  Company Management Reports  Shipment - Text Program
```

Note: There is a tab character before each "column"

Note 2: Each line has either 4 or 5 "columns"

Comment: Do any of the "related" questions on the bottom-right side of this page help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/   *//g' file
```

..............